# Selecting from Many to many

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I in Excel, resolve this question about this table:

```
Invoice Number | Item | Product  | Value
1001           | 1    | potatoes | 100
1001           | 2    | tomatoes | 150
1002           | 1    | potatoes | 100
1003           | 1    | water    | 50
1004           | 1    | potatoes | 100
1004           | 2    | onions   | 120
```

If I ask the questions:

Which an how many of these invoices have no potatoes or tomatoes ?
the answer should be, in this case: invoice 1003 / number = 1

How can I find it in Excel? Is there a formula for this question?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  But perhaps a pivot table would give you the information you are looking for.

Comment: look into using [SUMPRODUCT](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the helper column. Place the following formula in it:
`=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$C$2:$C$7,"potatoes")=0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$C$2:$C$7,"onions")=0),IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,A2,$E$1:$E1,"Ok")=0,"Ok",""),"")`

copy/paste the formula to the whole column, then you can use the count() function or filter by "Ok" values.
[image: =IF(AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$C$2:$C$7,"potatoes")=0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$C$2:$C$7,"onions")=0),IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,A2,$E$1:$E1,"Ok")=0,"Ok",""),"")]

Comment: thank u. That work fine! Do u think it's possible using pivot tables to find it easier ? or if I can use PowerPivot / PowerView to do it easier ?
That formula u provide its quite difficult to figure out :S

Comment: I am not sure about PivotTable, but PowerView is likely to work. 
For me, formulas are easier :). 

You can find a few examples of using COUNTIFS in the following tutorial:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/10/excel-countifs-multiple-criteria/   
I can elaborate on the formula's blocks if you wish, there's no rocket science there )

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want to use is [Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-d09e4d07-8cd6-4b60-afad-8fb67418800f?CorrelationId=dffe2493-2376-4f33-9d86-0823397cef5a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc263767342). It's really easy to do exactly what you want with just a few clicks once you learn how to use that feature.

Comment: hi, I don't think it's easily possible with pivot tables. I put the table above in a pivot table, but any filter I do and count I made keeps showing me invoices that have items with product 'potatoes' or 'tomatoes'...

Comment: what @nsa_a1 meant is, drop you "product" field into the filter section of your pivot table and deselect entries you want to omit.

Comment: I don't think you got it...there's a relation here of "one to many"...so even if I deselect the entries I want to omit, the invoices I need to omit still be there...